# Help fixing problem drive

Tags: hard-disk, zfs, corruption

I have a 3TB WD drive that had a ZFS pool with another drive making a single 6TB partition. That other drive failed and corrupted the data on this drive, I am trying to recover this drive, not the data, just the drive.

I have tried to create a new partition on it using GParted which fails, I keep on getting input/output errors.

---

**`sudo parted -l`**

```
Error: /dev/sdg: unrecognised disk label
Model: WD Ext HDD 1021 (scsi)                                             
Disk /dev/sdg: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

**`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdg`**

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdg: Input/output error
```

**`sudo smartctl --info /dev/sdg`**

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.7.10-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Green
Device Model:     WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0
Serial Number:    WD-WMAWZ0331282
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 25c42a0b6
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Feb 14 19:26:16 2017 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

ran short test for smart to check drive:

**`sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdg`**

**`sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdg`**

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.7.10-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

**`sudo parted /dev/sdg`**

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdg
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
```

**`(parted) mklabel gpt`**

```
Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sdg
Retry/Ignore/Cancel?
```

---

Comment: Look at your system's logs for details on what really happens.  I'm also wondering if the disk is still in the machine where it was part of the ZFS pool.  That's unclear.  Since I/O errors are very rarely due to software problems, you could save a lot of time by trying the disk in another machine since it might be defective.

Comment: Or perhaps something else in the mix?  Controller?  Cable?  Since some of your commands can "see" the drive, where as others cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `dmesg` and then plugged my drive in.  I saw some warnings about low voltage.  That's because I was plugging a hard disk drive into a raspberry pi and it didn't have enough power to spin up the disk.

Not sure if lack of power is your problem but it produced the same "Input/output error" in `fdisk` for me.  The `dmesg` readout would be helpful in diagnosing your problem.